# Does an enhancement bonus on ammunition impact attack rolls, or only damage rolls?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, weapons

It seems intuitive to me that firing +2 arrows out of a nonmagical longbow would give me a +2 bonus on damage, but not attack rolls; the arrows don't really have much of an impact on how well I can aim. By RAW, however, everything I've read would suggest that magical ammunition applies an enhancement bonus to attack rolls normally. Is there any clarification on this anywhere, or any supporting evidence for either side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, magic arrows are also better at hitting their target, not just damaging them. Nowhere in the rules does it say that ammunition only gets the damage benefit of its enhancement bonus.

Since there is no explicit exception attached to ammunition in general or magical arrows specifically, the [general explanation of what *+X magic weapon* means](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons) applies (emphasis mine):

> A magic weapon is enhanced to **strike more truly** and deliver more damage. Magic weapons have enhancement bonuses ranging from +1 to +5. **They apply these bonuses to both attack and damage rolls when used in combat.**

Comment: Though it might be worth mentioning the interaction of the two enhancement bonuses if the bow is also magical...